# how to make cmake find a package configuration file

Tags: qt, cmake, pyside

I'm trying to cmake a project which calls

```
find_package(Shiboken REQUIRED)
```

cmake complains about

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindShiboken.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Shiboken",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Shiboken" with any
  of the following names:

    ShibokenConfig.cmake
    shiboken-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Shiboken" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Shiboken_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Shiboken" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I do have Shiboken compiled and installed to C:\Program Files\shiboken. And I can see there are cmake files like ShibokenConfig.cmake, ShibokenConfig-python2.7.cmake, ShibokenConfigVersion.cmake under folder C:\Program Files\shiboken\lib\cmake\Shiboken-1.1.2

how do I let the cmake know it should search for ShibokenConfig.cmake in that folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of Shiboken's contributors answered my question through email and I confirmed it's working.

The solution:

```
cmake .. -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DShiboken_DIR=C:\shiboken\lib\cmake\Shiboken-1.1.2
```

Note： I copied C:\Program Files\shiboken to C:\shiboken because cmake complains about "C:\Program Files" (maybe caused by the space in it).